# row numbers in tibble after subsetting - R programming

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

How to display the row number after sub setting tibble .

Here is the example , first i am sub setting the classic data frame , results show me the observations with the row number (106,118,119,123 ... )

Below when i am sub setting tibble , it is not giving the observation rownumbers, instead it shows 1,2,3,4.....

Anyway to i can make tibble show the observation row number after sub setting?

```
> iris[iris$Sepal.Length >7.4,]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
> iris_tibble=as.tibble(iris)
> iris_tibble[iris_tibble$Sepal.Length >7.4,]
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>    
1          7.6         3            6.6         2.1 virginica
2          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
4          7.7         2.8          6.7         2   virginica
5          7.9         3.8          6.4         2   virginica
6          7.7         3            6.1         2.3 virginica
```

Comment: Since you are using the tidyverse you might want to filter instead of sub setting.  E.G. `iris_tibble <-
  rownames_to_column(iris) %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length > 7.4)`

Comment: Thanks @KerryJackson . i am imputing the missing values . Finding the row number will help me impute the values by directly specifying the row number. Is there a better way to impute missing values in tidyverse ??

Comment: In the `tidyverse`, you can use `coalesce` if you want to replace missing values with something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a column with row names and then do the filtering/subsetting.

Using `dplyr`:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(row_name = row_number())
```

Or using `tibble`:

```
rowid_to_column(iris, "row_name")
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think data.table supports row names. But you could do

```
iris <- iris %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    as.tibble(iris)
```

Then you should have a column that has the row numbers that will maintain when filtered.

Comment: `add_rownames` is deprecated, so I would suggest using `rownames_to_column()` instead.